# Tikz style with intermittent lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, line

How can I do this style with tikz?

[image]

I started with this, but I don't know how continue:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[block1/.style={draw, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm,rounded corners},
               >=Stealth]
\node[block1,label=above:text] (a) {one};
\node[block1, right=5cm of a] (b) {two};
\node[block1, right=5cm of b] (c) {three};

\draw [arrow] (a) ->  (b);
\draw [arrow] (b) ->  (c);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Produce:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proposal. Your code produced an error because of the `\draw[arrow]` lines, which I fixed.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[block1/.style={draw, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm,rounded corners},
               >=Stealth]
\node[block1,label=above:text] (a) {one};
\node[block1, right=5cm of a] (b) {two};
\node[block1, right=5cm of b] (c) {three};

\draw [->] (a) --  (b);
\draw [->] (b) --  (c);

\foreach \X in {a,b,c}
{
\draw[dashed,blue!50!white] (\X.west) --++(0,2cm) coordinate[midway] (\X-w);
\draw[dashed,blue!50!white] (\X.east) --++(0,2cm) coordinate[midway] (\X-e);
\draw[latex-latex,blue!50!white] (\X-w)-- (\X-e) coordinate[midway] (\X-top);
}
\node[above=2mm of a-top,anchor=south,text width=1.5cm] (a-bla){bla bla bla};
\node[above=2mm of b-top,anchor=south,text width=1.5cm] (b-bla){bla bla bla bla};
\node[above=2mm of c-top,anchor=south,text width=1.5cm] (c-bla){bla bla bla bla
bla};
%
\draw[latex-latex,blue!50!white] (a-e)-- (b-w) coordinate[midway] (ab-top);
\draw[latex-latex,blue!50!white] (b-e)-- (c-w) coordinate[midway] (bc-top);
\node[above=2mm of ab-top,anchor=south,text width=4.5cm,align=center] (ab-bla){bla bla bla};
\node[above=2mm of bc-top,anchor=south,text width=4.5cm,align=center] (bc-bla){bla bla bla bla};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you do not yet make use of the `arrows.meta` library.